# Is it possible to add optimized assembly file into *.c file as a inline assembly?

Tags: assembly

I generate `test.s` file using `gcc -S -O3 test.c`. There is a quick sort code in test.c. Is it possible to add assembly code of quick sort of `test.s` to  `test.c` file again instead of original quick sort `c` code?
Thanks

Comment: In general, you'd just keep it in its `.s` file and link your C code against it.

Comment: thanks but I dont want "in general" case..

Answer (score 0):

Almost certainly. If you have a compiler capable of using inline assembly (it's not mandated by the standard, rather it's an extension), then you can probably inject whatever code you wish.

My question would be "why?". If your compiler generates the optimised code in the first place, just let it do its job. In other words, compile all your code with high optimisation.

That way, if things change (better compiler, new architecture, etc), the code will auto-magically improve itself next time you compile, something that's not going to happen if you tell it to use your specific assembly instructions.

If, for some reason, you don't want *all* your code at high optimisation, you can split the sort code in to its own file and use different flags for just that one. But there's still no reason why it would have to be assembly.

If you really want to do it, it should be a (relatively) simple matter of mapping the `.s` file into the correct inline assembly format.

Comment: I have to submit high performance c code without optimization. I'm allowed to use inline assembly, so what I'm think about is produce optimized assembly code (using -O3 gcc)and insert this code as a inline assembly... but it doesn't work. I following inline assembly rule, and it compile succesfully, but can't execute! it aborted!

Comment: @user3595632 Your won't fool anyone with this. Your teacher is going to recognize the generated assembly for what it is.

Comment: @user3595632 Then your professor should be able to explain exactly how to do it.